# How to find the average time until a customer bought the same product again

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to find the average time a customer took to buy the same product in his consecutive orders.Suppose if a customer bought product X today in his first order and two days after he bought the same product X in his second order and like this many orders.

So is it possible to find the average time/Percentage of customers who bought the same order?

Magento Version : 1.9

Answer (score 1):

May be Follow below steps to get:

1. Get all order collection by customer wise
2. Get order item id from all order and store in array
3. Get order created time
4. then check and count one order item id how many times repeat.
5. if order item id is repeat then find both order time difference.

I hope it will help you.